# MongoDB Windows MSI installing Compass by default

Tags: mongodb, compass

I've installed MongoDB using the MSI from the downloads section however when installing it silently the installer also pre-populates and runs its own installation of Compass.

Now usually I wouldn't have an issue with this however Compass doesn't populate a registry setting with an uninstall string and subsequently doesn't get uninstalled.

I also have a seperate installation for Compass so the fact the MSI installs it automatically is annoying. The script it comes with reaches out to MongoDB and retrieves the latest version without prompting for any kind of acceptance.

I've seen a lot of answers on faulty Compass installs or where to find it but not a lot if you don't want it there.
Does anyone know whether there is an MSI flag or parameter I can call to not install Compass as a part of this installation?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you use the MSI installer? MongoDB is a single executable `mongod.exe` (and `mongos.exe` if you plan to deploy a shared cluster). There is no need for an installer, just unzip the zip file. [This page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongod.exe/) shows how you create the service and writing a [configuration file](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/) is also simple.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question.

Using lessmsi I unpacked the mongodb-windows-x86_64-x.x.x.msi.
To avoid installing Compass with MongoDB you should include the following **parameter**:

msiexec.exe /i .\mongodb-windows-x86_64-x.x.x.msi **SHOULD_INSTALL_COMPASS=0**

This will ensure Compass is not installed by the MSI.